# Puppet and composer project

Tags: linux, composer-php, puppet

A small puppet question

I am creating a composer project like so.

```
composer::project { 'project-test':
  ensure  => 'latest', #or installed?
  target => '/home/test/www',
  dev => false,
  require => Package ['php', 'apache']
}
```

And then from an exec I want to require it as a resource. How can I?

Example of exec:

```
exec { 'generate-tests' :
  command => 'php tests.php',
  path => '/usr/bin/',
  cwd => "/home/test/www/bin",
  logoutput => 'true',
  #require => composer::project['project-test']
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since what you're requiring is a resource, it should be capitalized as follows:

```
require => Composer::Project['project-test']
```